# Optional chaining and useState hook

Tags: reactjs

I get undefined if I replace my line 17 with cryptoInfo?.map .I used cryptoInfo in the useState hook.Is this due to the error in useState

```
const Cryptocurrencies = ({ simplified }) => {
  let count = simplified ? 10 : 100;
  const { data: cryptoList, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery(count);
  const [cryptoInfo, setCryptoInfo] = useState(cryptoList?.data?.coins);
  console.log(cryptoInfo);
  if (isFetching) return "Loading...";

  return (
    <>
      <Row gutter={[16, 16]} className="crypto-card-container">
        {cryptoList?.data?.coins?.map((currency) => (
          <Col
            xs={24}
            sm={12}
            xl={6}
            className="crypto-card"
            key={currency.uuid}
          >
         </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default Cryptocurrencies;
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what the problem is? It's currently unclear what you are trying to achieve and what's going wrong.

Comment: You don't need that intermediate state, that is your solution.

Comment: As said in another comment below, the solution is const coins = cryptoList?.data?.coins

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I assume your problem is that `cryptoInfo` is initialised with `undefined` because `useGetCryptosQuery(count)` seems to be an async function, that returns a value that is initially `undefined` and later gets updated - but at that point in time `cryptoInfo` is already initialised with `undefined` and does not get updated with the new value.

The quick fix would be to use `useEffect` to keep `cryptoInfo` always up to date:

```js
useEffect(
    () => setCryptoInfo(cryptoList?.data?.coins), 
    [cryptoList]
);
```

Comment: ... But since `setCryptoInfo` is not used by OP's code for anything, the real fix is `const cryptoInfo = cryptoList?.data?.coins;`.

Comment: But I have a question, Even though ```cryptoInfo``` is ```undefined``` it should not give any error because of optional chaining. Right?

Comment: This answer just validates bad practice, maybe it "fixes" (introducing multiple sources of truths, multiple additional and unwanted rerenders and probable other side effects) what OP is trying to achieve but it should not be the solution.

Comment: @mttetc I don't understand what you consider practice in the OPs code or in my answer, and where you see the causes for unwanted re-renders or side-effects. Could you clarify?

Comment: This answer shows a pattern the ReactJS docs call an anti pattern. If this is the only place the state gets used, use a [direct assignment ](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state), otherwise use a simple [if statement to set the data on change](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state)

Comment: @Ferrybig thanks for the clarification, I agree with your reasoning. I was assuming the OP's code was just a minimised example and that useState was used intentionally because it would be necessary in the original, non-minimised code.

Comment: Well, if you validate this pattern, then you'll send the message that it's a viable solution so juniors (like OP) will do it in every components. The component probably renders twice or thrice now because you are telling react to rerender the component when cryptoList changes, which is redundant. It's already handled in the query.